# PHP preg match can't work

Tags: php, notifications, match

I have problem with php's preg_match.I want to make something like this :
When someone on forum post someones username (example: @Username text..) to do the mysql query to insert notification to database.

I've made this code :

```
<?php 
$this = mysql_query("SELECT id,username FROM users");
while($the = mysql_fetch_array($this)){
if(preg_match("/^@".$the['username']."/",$form_text)){
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO notifications (num,who) VALUES ('$forum_id','".$the['username']."')");
}    
?>
```

But something is not working.How can i fix it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and use:

```
if (strpos( $form_text , $the['username'] ) !== false)
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: You should also protect yourself from SQL injections, lookup this page:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what is not working, the search of the text occurance (username), the mysql insertion, the notification?